# Cron expression for Amazon Eventbridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to get cron expression to trigger an event at 7:45 UTC on only working days -- Monday to Friday.

```
45 7 * * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
45 7 * * 1,2,3,4,5 *
```

Although the above expressions were supposed to work I am getting an Invalid CRON expression error raised on both and so how is the day of the week supposed to be to get it to work on only working days?

Comment: This answer will help you if you want to create eventBridge on the last day of the month but also only on working days MON-FRI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76289468/12326605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
45 7 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try this

```
45 7 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
45 7 ? * 1,2,3,4,5 *
```

or

```
45 7 ? * MON-FRI *
45 7 ? * 1-5 *
```

More examples are available at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html#eb-cron-expressions

Sri