# Create an EventBridge cron for last day of the month in Monday to Friday

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-event-bridge

I have searched a lot for a solution on the EventBridge for Amazon so I can use a cron which trigger a lambda function on the last day of the month in working days MON-FRI.

I cannot accomplish the working days part but here it is the last day cron.

```
30 13 L * ? *
```

This code will be triggered on the last day of the month. The ? is for every day but in fact I want 0-4 or MON-FRI.

If I enter it in the amazon cron tab it make an error for invalid cron expression.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this cron expression : `30 13 LW * ? *`

[image: Cron expression]

Here the `L` wildcard in the ***Day-of-month*** fields specifies the last day of the month. And the `W` wildcard in the ***Day-of-month*** field specifies a weekday. So in the ***Day-of-month*** field, `LW` specifies the last weekday closest to the month.

Ref: [Schedule Expressions for Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)